# confidence interval for arbitrary distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, algorithms

Let's say I have some random variable $X$ whose CDF can be evaluated exactly but cannot be Inverted .Can someone given me an algorithm or some pointer to  relevant source which talks about this.Every thing I search up for, is showing for confidence interval for normal distribution or parameter estimation. My question doesn't have anything to do with parameter estimation.

EDIT: given a $p$ I need to find values $b$ , $a$ s.t $F(b) - F(a) = p$ and $a< \mu<b$ . I think I need to do some kind of binary search for values of $a,b$ but I am not completely sure.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @StephanKolassa . I am trying to find confidence interval of random variable whose CDF is defined piecewise

Comment: @StephanKolassa given a $p$ I need values $b$ , $a$ s.t $F(b) - F(a) = p$ and $a< \mu<b$ . I think I need to do some kind of binary search for values of $a,b$ but I am not completely sure

Comment: So: you can *evaluate* the CDF at specific points, but you don't know the full CDF, is that correct? And: for what quantity are you trying to get a confidence interval? For the mean? (For the median, it would be easy.)

Comment: What you are [describing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466523/confidence-interval-for-arbitrary-distribution?noredirect=1#comment862051_466523) is not a confidence interval. It is a pair of quantiles that contain the mean.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I do know the full CDF but it's not simple.For example I can code it piecewise in python

Comment: @StephanKolassa ohh. I didn't know that .In that case How should I proceed ?

Comment: Well, you can find quantiles using bisection search. (They will not be uniquely defined.) So, do you *know* the mean and just need to make sure the quantiles contain it, or do you also need to numerically evaluate the mean for a CDF you can only define piecewise?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I do have (almost)analytically closed form of mean, and you can assume I can find pretty close approximation to mean from code.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Just another doubt.But if I want centered quantiles i.e., p/2 to left and p/2 to right of mean , then atleast in principal there are uniquely defined right ?

Comment: Yes, unless you have discontinuities at the exact points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple approach should work. As in: try it and look where it fails for your specific situation, then you know what you need to fix.

1. Use bisection search to find $a$ such that $F(a)=\frac{p}{2}$.
2. Use bisection search to find $b$ such that $F(b)=1-\frac{p}{2}$.
3. If $a\leq\mu\leq b$, you are done. If not:
4. If $\mu<a$, set $a':=a$ and use bisection search to find a $b'$ such that $F(b')=F(a')+p$. Do a similar thing if $\mu>b$.

You will need to think about what happens if $F$ is discontinuous at the exact quantiles you want, e.g., if it jumps right from $\lim_{x\to a^-}F(x)<\frac{p}{2}$ to $\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)>\frac{p}{2}$.

Comment: $b'$ s.t $ "F(b') F(a') +p"$ . There is no condition after s.t in your answer , can your please elaborate more at the end of 4th point ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an "=".

Comment: One more doubt but $b$ already satisfies condition that $F(b') = F(a') + p$ .So I think bisection search returns $b$ for $b'$. Is there any additional condition ?

Comment: Well, if you needed to change $a$ to $a'$ because $\mu<a$, then $F(b)>F(a')+p$, so you will need to change $b$ to $b'$.